# Unable to build to iPad after renewing provisioning profile

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios

I recently renewed a provisioning profile for an iPad app I am working on and now I am unable to build the app to the iPad.

First I renewed the profile in ADC, downloaded it and then dragged it to xCode. I then deleted the expired profile. Now when I attempt to build I get "Error from Debugger: The program being debugged is not being run." and I can't figure out why.

The app was working fine before I had to renew the profile. Also, I have already deleted completely from the iPad and tried to rebuild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i run into that, i usually do a clean build, try again, restart my iPad, try again, and then restart my mac, and try again. so far it has always started working again at one stage or another during this process.

Comment: I guess I didn't resert the iPad like I thought I did. Anyway worked for me. Thanks.